# Smooth shrink while reducing a span max-width inside a button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-animations

Context : I work with Bootstrap 4. I have many buttons with some SVG + span for the button text, like these :

```
<button class="btn--color-success">
    <span>Button label</span>
    <svg><svg>
</button>
```

I want to make the span disappear while clicking on the button, while I replace the svg by a loading one, making a "loading" button. The SVG switch is not the problem here, let's focus on the span & the button width.

I have no problem doing this with some max-width on the buttons span, but when I have two buttons inside a classic BS4 row/col with a justify-content-end alignment, the shrink is not very smooth... but I can't find a way to make it smoothier.

Here's a 400px wide container fiddle showing the problem

```css
body {
  max-width: 400px;
}
.row [class*='col-'] {
    transition: all .3s;
}
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content : center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
}
button span {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: max-width .3s;
}
button.btn--shrink span {
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PDle/QlgIONtM1aqA2Qemk5gPOE7wFq8+Em+G/hmo5Iq0CCmYZLv3fVRDJ4MMwEA" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button>
                <span>A button</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button onclick="this.classList.toggle('btn--shrink')">
                <span>A shrinkable button</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen many questions / answers on S/O but none could help to find the solution to my problem. I think it's pretty obvious but I can't help myself out of this think.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some flexbox stuff to fade out the span inside the button. Set each button to flex: 1; so that they retain the same width no matter what. I gave them a min-height and min-width as well in this example. I hope I interpreted your dilemma correctly.

Edit: Actually, I think i understand better now (maybe). I updated my answer with a little bit more code to make the buttons shrink more in tune with each other.

```js
$(".shrinker").on("click", function() {
      $(this).addClass("shrank").siblings().addClass("shrank");
    $(this).children("span").fadeToggle(600);
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: goldenrod;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  flex: 1;
  transition: .6s min-width ease-in-out, .6s flex ease-in-out;
}

.shrinker {
  position: relative;
}

.shrinker img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
}

.button span {
  display: flex;
}

.shrank {
  flex: 0;
}

.shrank > img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="button">
    <span>button one</span>
  </div>
  <div class="button shrinker">
    <span>shrinking btn</span>
    <img src="https://c.tenor.com/I6kN-6X7nhAAAAAj/loading-buffering.gif" />
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't quite understand your answer. The right button doesn't seem to shrink to the width of a short content (like an icon).

Answer (score 0):

Use transitions:

```js
function shrink(el) {
  el.innerHTML = "gone";
  el.style.minWidth = "20px";
}
```

```css
#shrinkable {
  min-width: 200px;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button id = 'normal'>Normal</button>
<button id = 'shrinkable' onclick = 'shrink(this)'>A Shrinkable Button</button>
```

Comment: Well, yes, thanks for the tip. There already are transitions on my buttons. I understand that it works on your example, but the point was to make it work with the HTML code I was submitting. I can't really just change the whole layout :/